# Thunderbolt networking on multiple Ubuntu versions not working

Tags: thunderbolt

I'm at a bit of a loss. My current setup uses a HP Omen 17 ck model (i7 11th gen) (rtx3070)
and a hp pro mini 400 g9. Currently I am trying to connect these 2 via thunderbolt (local network)

It works. Always has, via windows that is. Anytime I use Ubuntu, whether it be 20.04-22.04 - 22.10 or even 23.04. I get the following errors:

usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
thunderbolt 0000:00:0d.2: can't suspend (nhi_runtime_suspend [thunderbolt] returned -110)

Permissions are correctly set, even disabled on the Hp Pro Mini to allow devices to connect. Same on the laptop.

Is there any way for me to get this to work 100% of the time instead of 5%?
Unloading thunderbolt kernel module won't work, as this makes the thunderbolt chip go into an incorrect state. (and even trying to load it afterwards results in nothing happening). Is thunderbolt fully supported in Ubuntu? It seems not?

**Unloading module result>**

```
[  828.882424] thunderbolt 0000:00:0d.2: RX ring 0 already stopped
[  828.882454] WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 6656 at drivers/thunderbolt/nhi.c:733 tb_ring_stop+0xa2/0x1f0 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882473] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi cmac snd_sof_probes algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress snd_hda_codec_hdmi ac97_bus intel_rapl_msr snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_rapl_common snd_hda_intel intel_tcc_cooling snd_intel_dspcfg x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_intel_sdw_acpi intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec coretemp bnep i915 nouveau snd_hda_core snd_hwdep iwlmvm snd_pcm kvm_intel mxm_wmi btusb drm_buddy drm_ttm_helper joydev mac80211 ttm snd_seq_midi btrtl kvm snd_seq_midi_event drm_display_helper uvcvideo btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc libarc4 crct10dif_pclmul snd_rawmidi
[  828.882492]  cec btintel videobuf2_memops ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 binfmt_misc snd_seq rc_core btmtk aesni_intel iwlwifi crypto_simd videobuf2_common snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper hp_wmi mei_hdcp bluetooth mei_pxp cryptd snd_timer videodev i2c_algo_bit sparse_keymap nls_iso8859_1 spi_nor fb_sys_fops ecdh_generic input_leds ucsi_acpi intel_cstate mei_me cfg80211 platform_profile snd mc wmi_bmof mtd syscopyarea hid_multitouch ee1004 ecc serio_raw typec_ucsi mei sysfillrect soundcore sysimgblt typec mac_hid acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp ramoops pstore_blk drm parport reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 nvme nvme_core hid_generic sdhci_pci intel_lpss_pci i2c_hid_acpi i2c_i801 spi_intel_pci cqhci r8169 intel_lpss xhci_pci i2c_hid crc32_pclmul thunderbolt(-) i2c_smbus spi_intel sdhci realtek idma64 vmd xhci_pci_renesas wmi hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[  828.882534] CPU: 10 PID: 6656 Comm: rmmod Not tainted 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  828.882536] Hardware name: HP OMEN by HP Laptop 17-ck0xxx/88F7, BIOS F.41 09/08/2022
[  828.882537] RIP: 0010:tb_ring_stop+0xa2/0x1f0 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882542] Code: 0f 84 5c 01 00 00 48 81 c7 d0 00 00 00 e8 06 fc 80 cf 45 89 f0 4c 89 e1 4c 89 ea 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 ce c2 59 c0 e8 8e f0 ce cf <0f> 0b 48 89 df 4c 8d 63 50 e8 d0 52 dc cf 48 8b 7b 08 e8 07 53 dc
[  828.882543] RSP: 0018:ffff9f7b4aa43c90 EFLAGS: 00010046
[  828.882544] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8dff818a00c0 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  828.882545] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  828.882546] RBP: ffff9f7b4aa43cb0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  828.882546] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffc059c1a3
[  828.882547] R13: ffff8dff82d26fa0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8dff82c3b080
[  828.882558] FS:  00007f01a9980000(0000) GS:ffff8e0ed7a80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  828.882559] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  828.882560] CR2: 0000561d55eebc08 CR3: 00000001fd914003 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
[  828.882561] PKRU: 55555554
[  828.882561] Call Trace:
[  828.882562]  <TASK>
[  828.882564]  tb_ctl_stop+0x3c/0xf0 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882569]  tb_domain_remove+0x45/0x70 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882577]  nhi_remove+0x4b/0x70 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882583]  pci_device_remove+0x36/0xb0
[  828.882590]  device_remove+0x43/0x80
[  828.882596]  device_release_driver_internal+0x21a/0x2a0
[  828.882597]  driver_detach+0x4a/0xa0
[  828.882598]  bus_remove_driver+0x6c/0x100
[  828.882599]  driver_unregister+0x31/0x60
[  828.882600]  pci_unregister_driver+0x40/0x90
[  828.882602]  nhi_unload+0x10/0x51f [thunderbolt]
[  828.882612]  __do_sys_delete_module.constprop.0+0x18c/0x2a0
[  828.882615]  __x64_sys_delete_module+0x12/0x20
[  828.882616]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[  828.882633]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1dc/0x680
[  828.882635]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[  828.882637]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
[  828.882638]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
[  828.882639]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[  828.882641]  ? exc_page_fault+0x92/0x1b0
[  828.882642]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
[  828.882644] RIP: 0033:0x7f01a9126c9b
[  828.882645] Code: 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 95 21 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 83 c8 ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa b8 b0 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 65 21 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[  828.882646] RSP: 002b:00007fff953c3368 EFLAGS: 00000206 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000b0
[  828.882647] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000561d55ee0780 RCX: 00007f01a9126c9b
[  828.882648] RDX: 000000000000000a RSI: 0000000000000800 RDI: 0000561d55ee07e8
[  828.882648] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  828.882649] R10: 00007f01a91beac0 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 00007fff953c35c0
[  828.882652] R13: 0000561d55ee02a0 R14: 00007fff953c5796 R15: 0000561d55ee0780
[  828.882661]  </TASK>
[  828.882661] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  828.882666] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[  828.882667] thunderbolt 0000:00:0d.2: TX ring 0 already stopped
[  828.882679] WARNING: CPU: 10 PID: 6656 at drivers/thunderbolt/nhi.c:733 tb_ring_stop+0xa2/0x1f0 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882685] Modules linked in: rfcomm ccm snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_soc_hdac_hdmi cmac snd_sof_probes algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic ledtrig_audio snd_soc_dmic snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl snd_sof_intel_hda_common soundwire_intel soundwire_generic_allocation soundwire_cadence snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_pci snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_sof snd_sof_utils snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi soundwire_bus snd_soc_core snd_compress snd_hda_codec_hdmi ac97_bus intel_rapl_msr snd_pcm_dmaengine intel_rapl_common snd_hda_intel intel_tcc_cooling snd_intel_dspcfg x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_intel_sdw_acpi intel_powerclamp snd_hda_codec coretemp bnep i915 nouveau snd_hda_core snd_hwdep iwlmvm snd_pcm kvm_intel mxm_wmi btusb drm_buddy drm_ttm_helper joydev mac80211 ttm snd_seq_midi btrtl kvm snd_seq_midi_event drm_display_helper uvcvideo btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc libarc4 crct10dif_pclmul snd_rawmidi
[  828.882702]  cec btintel videobuf2_memops ghash_clmulni_intel videobuf2_v4l2 binfmt_misc snd_seq rc_core btmtk aesni_intel iwlwifi crypto_simd videobuf2_common snd_seq_device drm_kms_helper hp_wmi mei_hdcp bluetooth mei_pxp cryptd snd_timer videodev i2c_algo_bit sparse_keymap nls_iso8859_1 spi_nor fb_sys_fops ecdh_generic input_leds ucsi_acpi intel_cstate mei_me cfg80211 platform_profile snd mc wmi_bmof mtd syscopyarea hid_multitouch ee1004 ecc serio_raw typec_ucsi mei sysfillrect soundcore sysimgblt typec mac_hid acpi_pad acpi_tad sch_fq_codel msr parport_pc ppdev lp ramoops pstore_blk drm parport reed_solomon pstore_zone efi_pstore ip_tables x_tables autofs4 nvme nvme_core hid_generic sdhci_pci intel_lpss_pci i2c_hid_acpi i2c_i801 spi_intel_pci cqhci r8169 intel_lpss xhci_pci i2c_hid crc32_pclmul thunderbolt(-) i2c_smbus spi_intel sdhci realtek idma64 vmd xhci_pci_renesas wmi hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
[  828.882724] CPU: 10 PID: 6656 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G        W         5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[  828.882725] Hardware name: HP OMEN by HP Laptop 17-ck0xxx/88F7, BIOS F.41 09/08/2022
[  828.882725] RIP: 0010:tb_ring_stop+0xa2/0x1f0 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882730] Code: 0f 84 5c 01 00 00 48 81 c7 d0 00 00 00 e8 06 fc 80 cf 45 89 f0 4c 89 e1 4c 89 ea 48 89 c6 48 c7 c7 ce c2 59 c0 e8 8e f0 ce cf <0f> 0b 48 89 df 4c 8d 63 50 e8 d0 52 dc cf 48 8b 7b 08 e8 07 53 dc
[  828.882731] RSP: 0018:ffff9f7b4aa43c90 EFLAGS: 00010046
[  828.882731] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffff8dff818a1680 RCX: 0000000000000000
[  828.882732] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: 0000000000000000
[  828.882733] RBP: ffff9f7b4aa43cb0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  828.882733] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: ffffffffc059c19b
[  828.882733] R13: ffff8dff82d26fa0 R14: 0000000000000000 R15: ffff8dff82c3b080
[  828.882734] FS:  00007f01a9980000(0000) GS:ffff8e0ed7a80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  828.882735] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  828.882735] CR2: 0000561d55eebc08 CR3: 00000001fd914003 CR4: 0000000000770ee0
[  828.882736] PKRU: 55555554
[  828.882736] Call Trace:
[  828.882737]  <TASK>
[  828.882737]  tb_ctl_stop+0x45/0xf0 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882742]  tb_domain_remove+0x45/0x70 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882749]  nhi_remove+0x4b/0x70 [thunderbolt]
[  828.882754]  pci_device_remove+0x36/0xb0
[  828.882755]  device_remove+0x43/0x80
[  828.882756]  device_release_driver_internal+0x21a/0x2a0
[  828.882757]  driver_detach+0x4a/0xa0
[  828.882758]  bus_remove_driver+0x6c/0x100
[  828.882759]  driver_unregister+0x31/0x60
[  828.882760]  pci_unregister_driver+0x40/0x90
[  828.882761]  nhi_unload+0x10/0x51f [thunderbolt]
[  828.882770]  __do_sys_delete_module.constprop.0+0x18c/0x2a0
[  828.882771]  __x64_sys_delete_module+0x12/0x20
[  828.882772]  do_syscall_64+0x59/0x90
[  828.882773]  ? do_user_addr_fault+0x1dc/0x680
[  828.882774]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x2a/0x50
[  828.882776]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x3b/0xd0
[  828.882777]  ? irqentry_exit_to_user_mode+0x9/0x20
[  828.882778]  ? irqentry_exit+0x43/0x50
[  828.882779]  ? exc_page_fault+0x92/0x1b0
[  828.882780]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x63/0xcd
[  828.882781] RIP: 0033:0x7f01a9126c9b
[  828.882782] Code: 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 95 21 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48 83 c8 ff c3 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 90 f3 0f 1e fa b8 b0 00 00 00 0f 05 <48> 3d 01 f0 ff ff 73 01 c3 48 8b 0d 65 21 0f 00 f7 d8 64 89 01 48
[  828.882783] RSP: 002b:00007fff953c3368 EFLAGS: 00000206 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000b0
[  828.882784] RAX: ffffffffffffffda RBX: 0000561d55ee0780 RCX: 00007f01a9126c9b
[  828.882784] RDX: 000000000000000a RSI: 0000000000000800 RDI: 0000561d55ee07e8
[  828.882785] RBP: 0000000000000000 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000000
[  828.882785] R10: 00007f01a91beac0 R11: 0000000000000206 R12: 00007fff953c35c0
[  828.882786] R13: 0000561d55ee02a0 R14: 00007fff953c5796 R15: 0000561d55ee0780
[  828.882787]  </TASK>
[  828.882787] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
[  828.883337] ACPI: bus type thunderbolt unregistered
```

**Loading module result>**

```
ACPI: bus type thunderbolt registered
```

**Default error**

```
[  962.893480] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[  971.393547] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I was unable to find a solid solution.

I'm Currently using a minimal Windows installation as second OS in order to do my main stuff.
This seems to give me the best result in stability & connectivity.

Maybe I will retry on 23.04 after some time.